# Getting an URL which led to error (404) from error-page controller in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, error-handling

Say, i have a Spring MVC application with the following web.xml entry:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404</location>
</error-page>
```

and following error-page controller:

```
@RequestMapping({"","/"})
@Controller
public class RootController {

    @RequestMapping("error/{errorId}")
    public String errorPage(@PathVariable Integer errorId, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("errorId",errorId);

        return "root/error.tile";
    }
}
```

Now user requested non-existent URL /user/show/iamnotauser which triggered error page controller. How do i get this non-existent '/user/show/iamnotauser' URL from errorPage() method of RootController to put it into model and display on error page ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The trick is request attribute `javax.servlet.forward.request_uri`, it contains the original requested uri.

```
@RequestMapping("error/{errorId}")
public ModelAndView resourceNotFound(@PathVariable Integer errorId,
                                                   HttpServletRequest request) {
    //request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
    String origialUri = (String) request.getAttribute(
                                               RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);

    return new ModelAndView("root/error.jspx", "originalUri", origialUri);
}
```

If you still use Servlet API 2.5, then the constant `RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI` does not exist, but you can use `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")`. *or upgrad to `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1`*

Comment: We are on a server supporting Servlet API 3.0.x but using 2.5 as of specification in the web.xml. With this setting the approaches above didn't yield anything usefull, but `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");` did the trick